# Loading Text File in Ruby in Windows

Tags: ruby

Aptana is returning:

```
Invalid escape character syntax
File.open("C:\Users\C*****\Documents\RubyProjects\text.txt
```

What do I do?

Comment: Add a closing quote and paren?

Comment: I think you meant something like `C:\Users\C?????\Documents\RubyProjects\text.txt` or `C:\Users\C*\Documents\RubyProjects\text.txt` - the star wildcard means "zero or more characters", question mark means "any character"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby doesn't need you to use reverse slashes. In your string

```
"C:\Users\C*****\Documents\RubyProjects\text.txt"
```

you're confusing Ruby because you have reverse-slashes, which denote escapes in a double-quoted (interpreted) string and make Ruby throw up. Instead use:

```
"C:/Users/C*****/Documents/RubyProjects/text.txt"
```

From [the IO documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/IO.html):

> Ruby will convert pathnames between different operating system conventions if possible. For instance, on a Windows system the filename "/gumby/ruby/test.rb" will be opened as "\gumby\ruby\test.rb". When specifying a Windows-style filename in a Ruby string, remember to escape the backslashes:

```
"c:\\gumby\\ruby\\test.rb"
```

> Our examples here will use the Unix-style forward slashes; File::ALT_SEPARATOR can be used to get the platform-specific separator character.

Answer (score 3):

`\` is an escape charecter in most languages, so the compiler expects an escaped char after it, in this case its also `\`, so you just need to use 2 of them

```
File.open("C:\\Users\\C*****\\Documents\\RubyProjects\\text.txt
```